# How can I create 'Swipe on a message to reply on WhatsApp' kind of view using custom view on list?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-custom-view

I have a list of items in list view, I want to display the item that user swipes left on, in a new fragment or activity as a textview. I want the entire list to animate and move a bit to left as if it has been pulled to left with the finger. I want to execute the same using **custom views**.

[image: image reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add Swipeable behavior to your `RecyclerView` like this :

[Add Swipeable Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366919/how-to-add-swipe-left-to-right-in-recyclerview)

or use an external library to do that for you :

[Use External Lib](https://medium.com/android-news/android-recyclerview-swipeable-items-46a3c763498d)

Comment: I want the entire list to animate and move a bit to left as if it has been pulled to left with the finger?

Comment: Yeah exactly you can do that

Answer (score 0):

I think the following post gives the most detailed equation for this behaviour. It relates the finger position to the bubble position and can be customised easily.

```
xb = min( xf, f * sqrt(W) * sqrt(xf) )

xb = x-displacement of bubble from its initial position
xf = x-displacement of finger from its initial position
W  = screen width or maximum finger displacement possible
f  = maximum bubble displacement fraction or xb(max)/xf(max)
```

Here is the complete post
https://medium.com/@duolop/swipe-to-reply-animation-a-physics-based-approach-5ef646c396e4